# Java JSON delete while passing cookie

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver, session-cookies

I am using Selenium 2 against an EXT JS 5.1 application. I am trying to clean up a grid after running a test by removing all the present rows in that grid.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"checkForPrecautions"})
    public void cleanUp() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        authCookie = driver.manage().getCookieNamed(".ASPXAUTH").getValue();

        URL deleteURL = null;
        URL getUrl = new URL(precautionsAssignedAPI);

        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) getUrl.openConnection();
            request.setRequestProperty("Cookie", authCookie);
            request.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.setRequestMethod("GET");
            request.connect();

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement precJson = parser.parse(request.getContent().toString());
        JsonArray requestArray = (JsonArray) precJson
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .getAsJsonArray("results");

        int numOfPrecautions = requestArray.size();

        JsonArray precaution = (JsonArray) requestArray;
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfPrecautions ; i++){
            deleteURL = new URL(precautionsDeletedAPI + precaution.get(i));
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, deleteURL);
            HttpURLConnection delete = (HttpURLConnection) deleteURL.openConnection();
            delete.setRequestProperty("Cookie", authCookie);
            delete.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            delete.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            delete.connect();


        }
}
```

I am trying to use the API directly, but when I run this test, I get a 401 on the line

```
JsonElement precJson = parser.parse(request.getContent().toString());
```

I admit I am not well versed in these particular tasks so it may be something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

It was something simple and overlooked. I was trying to send the UI login cookie instead of using the api to login and send that cookie.